# How to double the size of a boolean mask with "False"- elements in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way in TensorFlow to double the size of a boolean mask tensor with "False"-elements? In other words, after each element I want to append a "False"-element.

For example my boolean mask looks as follows:

```
Mask = [True False True False]
```

After doubling the size with "False"-elements it should look like this:

```
Mask = [True False False False True False False False]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `False` mask with the same shape, stack it with the original `mask` and then flatten it with `reshape`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

mask = tf.constant([True, False, True, False])

mask_false = tf.constant(False, shape=mask.shape)
mask_stack = tf.stack((mask, mask_false), axis=1)
tf.reshape(mask_stack, (-1,)).eval()

# array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: For whoever didn't get it (like me) `axis=1` in stack results in a matrix of 2 columns which consist of the mask elements paired with False.